# Why orderByChild does not sort in AngularFire for Realtime database?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to order an acccount list using `orderByChild` using `dateCreated` field, but the return list(response) is not sorted by `dateCreated`

```
 this.angularDb.list('accounts', ref => ref
        .orderByChild('dateCreated').startAt(0).limitToFirst(10)
        ).valueChanges()
        .subscribe(response => {
            for (let item of response) {
              this.tableData.push(item);
            }
     
         }, error => {
            console.log(error);
         });
    
  }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I cannot find any source solve this issue

Comment: Actually the problem is with date field only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer which is that firebase does not support sorting dates: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order